# positioning html elements vertically in the right order

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a fraction in html [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chwdxz5y/2/), but I can't have the fraction bar put in between the elements "fup" and "fdn".

Here is the html:

```
<div class="fraction" id="f1">
    <div class="fup" id="0">
        <div id="addition_1">
            <div class="numeric" id="num_0">2</div>
            <div class="operator" id="op_0">+</div>
            <div class="numeric" id="num_1">1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar" id="bar_01"></div>
    <div class="fdn">
        <div class="numeric" id="1">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.fraction {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    letter-spacing: 0.001em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120px;
}

.bar {
    border-top: thin solid black;
    display: block;
 }


.numeric { 
     float: left;
     font-size: 120px;
     cursor: pointer;
}


.operator {
     float: left;
     font-size: 120px;
}
```

Please note that I need to keep the html structure as it is here, because I will put some jquery later that will require it. Also I need to have the fraction bar a separate html element.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, could you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I changed the css for `bar` into:

```
.bar {
    border-top: thin solid black;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
 }
```